# How can use the mapping node for two noise textures

Tags: node-editor

I'm actually creating a planet with this node set up : [image: node setup]

I would like the continent texture to be appearing only near the poles but they keep appearing randomly like this : 
I guess I have to use the mapping node in some ways but I can't fix it 
Does anyone have a solution ?

[image: render]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a geometry node which allows to use the rendered position to do this kind of thing.

[image]

The additional nodes can be plugged before the top left colorramp of your material:

[image]

From left to right (the top nodes line):

- Rendered position: the position is given from the object origin
- Separate XYZ, in order to keep only Z (for the poles)
- Absolute: the sphere here is 2 meters height and its origin is a the middle, so "absolute" gives a value between 0 and 1
- A color ramp to be tuned so that the earth surface is more or less far from the poles
- Multiply: to mix your noise input with the previous ramp which translates the Z value
- The last output is injected in the color ramp of your initial material (or at least I've tried to mimic it)

[image]

Comment: Thanks you ! I was looking in the wrong direction !